# Create archive under Debian right click menu does not allow password protection

Tags: debian, gui, 7z, p7zip

When trying to create an archive with Debian GUI using **Create archive...** from right-click menu and **Create a new archive** window, is there an option to assign a password to 7z archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `file-roller` package will replace pack dialog with **Compress** window which has pass option.